# PDF in iframe doesn't reload when I click a link to another page of the PDF

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

I have an iframe in my page in which I display a PDF.

```
<iframe src="test.pdf#page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=200&toolbar=1&navpanes=0" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Somwhere else on the page I have a link to another page of the same PDF like this:

```
<a target="test.pdf#page=2&view=FitH,0&zoom=200&toolbar=1&navpanes=0">pdf page 2</a>
```

But when i click the link, nothing happens. If I put another link in like google or another page from my site, these links open just fine.
But if I first click a link (targeted to the iframe) to another page (e.g. google or index.html) and then I click on the link to page 2 of the PDF, it realods like I want it to: It opens page 2 of the PDF in the iframe.

How can i make the links to other pages of the PDF open in the iframe without first opening another link.

P.S.

The link to the pages are just temporary. In the end i want the links to go to certain chapters in the PDF.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The target should be the name of the frame that will load the new item, and the href should specify what to load. For example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf" id="iframe"></iframe>

<a href="http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw7.pdf" target="iframe">pdf page 2</a>
```

Try that and see if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I actually had something like what you said. I posted it wrong here. The problem stil remains like I said above:(
But thanks for your fast reply.

Comment: We may be able to better assist you if you show exactly what your code is and describe what you are looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first erase the src and reload the same pdf file with the new page number. However a little delay of at least 50ms is required

document.getElementById("iframe").src ="";

setTimeout(function()
{document.getElementById("iframe").src = "Your.pdf#page=255&zoom=95&pagemode=none"}, 50);